# Composer autoloaded files debug

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to autoload a non class based file via composer

```
"autoload" : {
    "files": ["app/routes.php"]
},
```

But i am unable to get the contents of this file in my scripts. I have included the `vendor/autoload.php` as well as ran `dump-autoload`.

What i want is if there is a way that we can see the list of files that are being autoloaded by composer in browser or in terminal so that i can be sure that the autoloading is working fine and there is some other problem in my code.

Thanks

**Updated: File Heiarchy**

**Index.php**

```
/**
 * Including the Composer's autoloader
 */
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Bootstrap our application
 */
require_once 'app/init.php';
```

**Init.php**

```
<?php var_dump($route); ?>
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php
$route = 'abc';
?>
```

So my problem is i want to access $route variable in my `init.php` file.

Comment: I think you shouldn't ask a new question if your old question has some reactions as comments and is all in all way better describing the situation.

Comment: @Sven I apologize for this. At the time i posted this new question there was not any answer to satisfy that is why i asked this question with a new format

Answer (score 3):

I've look in the `autoload_real.php`, and I've noticed that the files aren't included in the global scope.

```
public static function getLoader()
{
    [...]

    $includeFiles = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_files.php';
    foreach ($includeFiles as $file) {
        require $file;
    }

    [...]
}
```

See [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php). Just add an `echo "test";` in your routes.php file to confirm that it is properly included. Then you may want change `routes.php` with something like

```
function getRoutes()
{
    return "abc";
}
```

and `Init.php`

```
<?php var_dump(getRoutes()); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the autoload.php file generated by Composer?

```
require_once 'path/to/autoload.php';
```

Also, note that the file will be loaded on **every** request

Comment: Are you talking abotu `vendor/autoload.php` ? provided by composer ?

Comment: yes that file is included

Comment: Please see i have updated my question so that i would be more clear of the code flow and problem